# MVC 4 and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 4 to `GET` and `POST` requests using JQuery but it seems that I cannot get JQuery to send the requests nor get the response from the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function search() {
        var lat = $('#latitude').val();
        var long = $('#longitude').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "api/Attractions/?longitude=" + long + "&latitude=" + lat,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == null) {
                    $('#attractionName').html("No attractions to search");
                }
                else {
                    $('#attractionName').html("You should visit " + data.Name);
                    displayMap(data.Location.Geography.WellKnownText, data.Name);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Get Geo Information
    function displayMap(coordinateString, name) {
        // WellKnownText is in format 'POINT (<longitude>, <latitude>)'
        coordinateString = coordinateString.replace("POINT (", "").replace(")", "");
        var long = coordinateString.substring(0, coordinateString.indexOf(" "));
        var lat = coordinateString.substring(coordinateString.indexOf(" ") + 1);

        // Show map centered on nearest attraction
        var map = new VEMap('myMap');
        map.LoadMap(new VELatLong(lat, long), 15, VEMapStyle.Aerial);

        // Add a pin for the attraction
        var pin = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, new VELatLong(lat, long));
        pin.SetTitle(name);
        map.AddShape(pin);
    }
</script>
```

And then, the button code:

```
<h1>Find the Closest Tourist Attraction</h1>
<div>
    <label for="longitude">Longitude:</label>
    <input type="text" id="longitude" size="10" />
    <label for="latitude">Latitude:</label>
    <input type="text" id="latitude" size="10" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="search();" />
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you done any debugging to see if any code gets executed or where the execution stops?

Comment: Button does not even fire the event <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="search();" />

Comment: Maybe you can try changing the button to: <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="javascript:search();" />
(Sorry, don't have the ability to test that right now.)

Comment: Use the developer tools in Chrome, Firefox or IE and stick a few breakpoints in your JS...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the URL helper. The url in the ajax call should look somewhat like this, I havent tested it but I know for a fact that I had to do this to fix the issue.

```
url:"@Url.Action("action", "controller")" + "?longitude=" + etc..
```